# Return String from onPostExecute

Tags: android-asynctask

I catch a string from json with asynctask. I would like send catched string to another class to insert database.

```
TranslatedWord trWord=new TranslatedWord();

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
        String text = result.getString(0); //Catched string here

        trWord.setTranslatedWord(text);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I created a new class to keep string. But I failed

```
public class TranslatedWord {
    private String trWord;

    public void setTranslatedWord(String trWord) {
        this.trWord = trWord;
    }

    public String getTrWord() {
        return trWord;
    }

    public void setTrWord(String trWord) {
        this.trWord = trWord;
    }
}
```

I call string with this code

```
String translatedWord = trWord.getTrWord();
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class TranslatedWord {

    private static String trWord;

    public String getTrWord() {
        return trWord;
    }

    public void setTrWord(String trWord) {
        this.trWord = trWord;
    }
}
```

I just made variable static. Its run.